# Oracle Referencing Primary Key

Tags: sql, oracle, foreign-keys, primary-key

Primary key of parent got its value from sequence customerNo = customerSeq.nextval. How do I insert that value into child table as foreign key?

> insert into account values (accountSeq.nextval,'500',customerSeq.nextval,'S','O');

doesn't work and give me error.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `currval` to get the last generated value.

```
insert into account 
  (account_id, some_col, customer_id, col3, col4)
values 
  (accountSeq.nextval,'500',customerSeq.currval,'S','O');
```

It's good coding style to explicitely list the columns of the table in the insert table. You also didn't show your table definition, but do not use String literals for numbers `'500'` is a string, `500` is a number.

More details are in the manual: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/pseudocolumns002.htm#i1009336

Answer (score 0):

When you insert a record into a table with a sequence, you use the "returning" clause to retrieve the value used into a PL/SQL variable, and then use that for child records.

```
insert into
  my_table (
    id,
    col1,
    ...)
  values (
    my_table_seq.nextval,
    'A',
    ...)
  returning id
  into      my_package.my_table_id;

insert into
   child_table (
     id,
     my_table_id,
     ...)
   values (
     child_table_seq.nextval,
     my_package.my_table_id,
     'B',
     ...)
```